# Centrar verticalmente y horizontalmente un div

Tags: css, css3

Estoy aprendiendo a utilizar los keyframes y animation de CSS3.

Estoy creando una Galaxia y deseo poner un texto pero no logro centrarlo verticalmente, he intentado de todo pero no lo he logrado. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

```css
* {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
@keyframes move-twink-back {
    from {background-position:0 0;}
    to {background-position:-5000px 5000px;}
}
@keyframes move-clouds-back {
    from {background-position: 0;}
    to {background-position:10000px 0;}
}

@keyframes move-clouds-back-red {
    from {background-position: 0;}
    to {background-position:10000px 0;}
}

@keyframes small-meteor {
  0%   {background-size:15px;}
  25%  {background-size:20px;}
  50%  {background-size:25px;}
  75%  {background-size:20px;}
  100% {background-size:15px;}
}

@keyframes move-meteor1-sm {
  from {background-position:500px -500px;}
  to   {background-position:80px 900px;}
}
@keyframes move-meteor2-sm{
  from {background-position:800px -80px;}
  to   {background-position:380px 900px;}
}
@keyframes move-meteor3-sm{
  from {background-position:100px -300px;}
  to   {background-position:-180px 900px;}
}
@keyframes move-meteor4-sm{
  from {background-position:2500px 100px;}
  to   {background-position:1200px 900px;}
}
@keyframes move-meteor5-sm{
  from {background-position:1200px 100px;}
  to   {background-position:800px 900px;}
}

@keyframes big-meteor {
  0%   {background-size:35px;}
  25%  {background-size:45px;}
  50%  {background-size:55px;}
  75%  {background-size:45px;}
  100% {background-size:35px;}
}
@keyframes move-meteor1-bg{
  from {background-position:680px -150px;}
  to   {background-position:100px 900px;}
}
@keyframes move-meteor2-bg{
  from {background-position:1500px -10px;}
  to   {background-position:850px 900px;}
}
@keyframes move-meteor3-bg{
  from {background-position:1000px -500px;}
  to   {background-position:450px 900px;}
}
@keyframes move-meteor4-bg{
  from {background-position:250px -850px;}
  to   {background-position:-550px 900px;}
}

@keyframes medium-meteor{
  0%   {background-size:25px;}
  25%  {background-size:30px;}
  50%  {background-size:35px;}
  75%  {background-size:30px;}
  100% {background-size:25px;}
}

@keyframes move-meteor1-md{
  from {background-position:380px -10px;}
  to   {background-position:-450px 1900px;}
}
@keyframes move-meteor2-md{
  from {background-position:950px -10px;}
  to   {background-position:450px 1900px;}
}
 
@keyframes brightness-sun{
  20%  {box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 3px #FF7A20;
  background-color: #ff6700;}
  40%  {box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 5px #FF6320;
  background-color: #ff4d00;}
  60%  {box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 7px #FF7A20;
  background-color: #ff6700;}
  80%  {box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 5px #FF6320;
  background-color: #ff4d00;}
  100% {box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 0px #FF9120;
  background-color: #ff8100;}
}

/*@keyframes ray_anim { 
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); transform: rotate(0deg);}    
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg);}
}*/

#stars, #twinkling, #clouds-red, #clouds-red2, #clouds-red3, #clouds-black, .meteor,
#container-sun
{
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
}

/*
** Sun
*/
#container-sun{
  top:-65px;
  left:-75px;
  z-index:2;
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background-color: #ff8100;
  opacity:0.75;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 0px #FF9120; 
  animation: brightness-sun 10s linear infinite;
}

#container-sun > .container-ray {
  position:absolute;
  margin:auto;
  top:0px;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  width:70px;
  animation: ray_anim 120s linear infinite;
}

#container-sun > .container-ray > .ray {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.8) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.8) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); 
    margin-left:10px;
    border-radius:80% 80% 0 0;
    position:absolute;
  
  z-index:2;
    opacity:0.2;
}

.ray-bg{
  height:170px;
  width:20px;
}
@keyframes size-ray-sm{ 
 0%   {height:100px;}
  10%  {height:95px;}
  20%  {height:90px;}
  30%  {height:85px;}
  40%  {height:80px;}
  50%  {height:75px;}
  60%  {height:80px;}
  70%  {height:85px;}
  80%  {height:90px;}
  90%  {height:95px;}
  100% {height:100px;}
}
.ray-sm{
  height: 100px;
  width: 10px;
}

/*Big ray*/
.ray1 {    
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    top:165px;
    left: 15px;
}

.ray-sm.ray2{
  animation: size-ray-sm 3s linear infinite, move-ray2 3s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes move-ray2{
  0% {transform: rotate(-30deg);top: 150px;left: 85px;}
  10% {left:84px;}
  20% {left:83px;}
  30% {left:82px;}
  40% {left:81px;}
  50% {transform: rotate(-31deg);left:80px;}
  60% {left:81px;}
  70% {left:82px;}
  80% {left:83px;}
  90% {left:84px;}
  100% {transform: rotate(-30deg);top: 150px;left: 85px;}
}

.ray-sm.ray4{
  animation: size-ray-sm 3s linear infinite, move-ray4 3s linear infinite;
} 
@keyframes move-ray4{
  0% {transform: rotate(-78deg);top: 45px;left: 150px;}
  10% {left:149px;}
  20% {top:46px;left:148px;}
  30% {left:147px;}
  40% {left:146px;}
  50% { transform: rotate(-79deg);left:145px;}
  60% {left:146px;}
  70% {left:147px;}
  80% {top:46px;left:148px;}
  90% {left:149px;}
  100% {transform: rotate(-78deg);top: 45px;left: 150px;}
}
/*Small ray*/
.ray2 {    
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
    top: 150px;
    left: 85px;
}

/*Big ray*/
.ray3 {
  transform: rotate(-50deg);
  top: 95px;
  left: 150px; 
}

/*Small ray*/
.ray4 {
  transform: rotate(-78deg);
  top: 45px;
  left: 150px;   
}

.meteor{
  /*background: transparent url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/139/139699.svg') no-repeat top center;*/
  /*background: transparent url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/180/180707.svg') no-repeat top center;*/
  /*background: transparent url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/728/728096.svg') no-repeat top center;*/
  background: transparent url('http://i.imgur.com/KgvLW3q.png') no-repeat top center;
  /*background: transparent url('https://i.imgur.com/hwRmI29.png') no-repeat top center;*/
  
  background-size:25px;
}

/*
** Small meteors
*/

.meteor1-sm, .meteor2-sm, .meteor3-sm, .meteor4-sm, .meteor5-sm{
  z-index:2;
}

.meteor1-sm{
  animation:small-meteor 16s linear infinite, move-meteor1-sm 16s linear infinite;
}

.meteor2-sm{
  animation:small-meteor 16s linear infinite, move-meteor2-sm 16s linear infinite;
}

.meteor3-sm{
  animation:small-meteor 16s linear infinite, move-meteor3-sm 16s linear infinite;
}

.meteor4-sm{
  animation:small-meteor 16s linear infinite, move-meteor4-sm 16s linear infinite;
}

.meteor5-sm{
  animation:small-meteor 16s linear infinite, move-meteor5-sm 16s linear infinite;
}

/*
** Big meteors
*/

.meteor1-bg, .meteor2-bg, .meteor3-bg, .meteor4-bg{
  z-index:6;
}
.meteor1-bg{
  animation:big-meteor 8s linear infinite, move-meteor1-bg 8s linear infinite;
}

.meteor2-bg{
  animation:big-meteor 8s linear infinite, move-meteor2-bg 8s linear infinite;
}

.meteor3-bg{
  animation:big-meteor 8s linear infinite, move-meteor3-bg 8s linear infinite;
}

.meteor4-bg{
  animation:big-meteor 8s linear infinite, move-meteor4-bg 8s linear infinite; 
}

/*
** Medium meteors
*/
.meteor1-md, .meteor2-md{
  z-index:4;
}

.meteor1-md{
  animation:medium-meteor 12s linear infinite, move-meteor1-md 12s linear infinite; 
}

.meteor2-md{
  animation:medium-meteor 12s linear infinite, move-meteor2-md 12s linear infinite; 
}

/*
** Stars
*/

#stars {
  background:#000 url('http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/360/images/stars.png') repeat top center;
  z-index:0;
}


/*
** Twinkling stars
*/
#twinkling{
  background:transparent url('http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/360/images/twinkling.png') repeat top center;
  z-index:1;
  
  -moz-animation:move-twink-back 100s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation:move-twink-back 100s linear infinite;
  -o-animation:move-twink-back 100s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation:move-twink-back 150s linear infinite;
  animation:move-twink-back 150s linear infinite;
}

/*
** Black clouds
*/
#clouds-black{
    background:transparent url('http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/360/images/clouds2.png') repeat-x left top;
  z-index:2;
   opacity:0.7;
  -moz-animation:move-clouds-back 200s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation:move-clouds-back 200s linear infinite;
  -o-animation:move-clouds-back 200s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation:move-clouds-back 200s linear infinite;
  animation:move-clouds-back 280s linear infinite;
}

/*
** Red clouds
*/

#clouds-red {
  z-index:3;
}

/*
** Movement of red clouds
*/
#clouds-red, #clouds-red2, #clouds-red3 {
  background: transparent url('http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/360/images/clouds3.png') repeat-x left center;
  
  -moz-animation:move-clouds-back-red 200s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation:move-clouds-back-red 200s linear infinite;
  -o-animation:move-clouds-back-red 200s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation:move-clouds-back-red 200s linear infinite;
  animation:move-clouds-back-red 200s linear infinite;
}
#clouds-red2{
  z-index:4;
}
#clouds-red3{
  z-index:5;
}

#word{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  text-align:center;
}

#word:before{
  content: "";
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  height:100%;
}
 
#word > div{
  max-width:100%;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  font-size:50px;
  z-index:10;
  background: orange;
  position:absolute;
  color: #FFDD1B;
  font-family: Pacifico;
}

#word > div:hover{
  color:#FFF;
  animation: neon 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes neon {
  from {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #FFDD1B, 0 0 70px #FFDD1B, 0 0 80px #FFDD1B, 0 0 100px #FFDD1B, 0 0 150px #FFDD1B;
  }
  to {
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 15px #fff, 0 0 20px #FFDD1B, 0 0 35px #FFDD1B, 0 0 40px #FFDD1B, 0 0 50px #FFDD1B, 0 0 75px #FFDD1B;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="word">
  <div>Galaxy</div>
</div>
<div id="container-sun">
  <div class="container-ray">
    <div class="ray ray-bg ray1"></div>
    <div class="ray ray-sm ray2"></div>
    <div class="ray ray-bg ray3"></div>
    <div class="ray ray-sm ray4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="stars"></div>
<div id="twinkling"></div>
<div id="clouds-red"></div>
<div id="clouds-red2"></div>
<div class="meteor meteor1-sm"></div>
<div class="meteor meteor2-sm"></div>
<div class="meteor meteor3-sm"></div>
<div class="meteor meteor4-sm"></div>
<div class="meteor meteor1-md"></div>
<div class="meteor meteor2-md"></div>
<div class="meteor meteor1-bg"></div>
<div class="meteor meteor2-bg"></div>
<div class="meteor meteor3-bg"></div>
<div class="meteor meteor4-bg"></div>
<div id="clouds-red3"></div>
<div id="clouds-black"></div>
```

Comment: ¿Sirve alguna respuesta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una opción con flexbox, utilizando sus famosas propiedades para centrar en ambos ejes:

```
display:flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

Aunque hay que agregar el típico código:

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}
```

No logré verificar rápidamente si esto afecta algunas animaciones.

```css
* {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
@keyframes move-twink-back {
    from {background-position:0 0;}
    to {background-position:-5000px 5000px;}
}
@keyframes move-clouds-back {
    from {background-position: 0;}
    to {background-position:10000px 0;}
}

@keyframes move-clouds-back-red {
    from {background-position: 0;}
    to {background-position:10000px 0;}
}

@keyframes small-meteor {
  0%   {background-size:15px;}
  25%  {background-size:20px;}
  50%  {background-size:25px;}
  75%  {background-size:20px;}
  100% {background-size:15px;}
}

@keyframes move-meteor1-sm {
  from {background-position:500px -500px;}
  to   {background-position:80px 900px;}
}
@keyframes move-meteor2-sm{
  from {background-position:800px -80px;}
  to   {background-position:380px 900px;}
}
@keyframes move-meteor3-sm{
  from {background-position:100px -300px;}
  to   {background-position:-180px 900px;}
}
@keyframes move-meteor4-sm{
  from {background-position:2500px 100px;}
  to   {background-position:1200px 900px;}
}
@keyframes move-meteor5-sm{
  from {background-position:1200px 100px;}
  to   {background-position:800px 900px;}
}

@keyframes big-meteor {
  0%   {background-size:35px;}
  25%  {background-size:45px;}
  50%  {background-size:55px;}
  75%  {background-size:45px;}
  100% {background-size:35px;}
}
@keyframes move-meteor1-bg{
  from {background-position:680px -150px;}
  to   {background-position:100px 900px;}
}
@keyframes move-meteor2-bg{
  from {background-position:1500px -10px;}
  to   {background-position:850px 900px;}
}
@keyframes move-meteor3-bg{
  from {background-position:1000px -500px;}
  to   {background-position:450px 900px;}
}
@keyframes move-meteor4-bg{
  from {background-position:250px -850px;}
  to   {background-position:-550px 900px;}
}

@keyframes medium-meteor{
  0%   {background-size:25px;}
  25%  {background-size:30px;}
  50%  {background-size:35px;}
  75%  {background-size:30px;}
  100% {background-size:25px;}
}

@keyframes move-meteor1-md{
  from {background-position:380px -10px;}
  to   {background-position:-450px 1900px;}
}
@keyframes move-meteor2-md{
  from {background-position:950px -10px;}
  to   {background-position:450px 1900px;}
}
 
@keyframes brightness-sun{
  20%  {box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 3px #FF7A20;
  background-color: #ff6700;}
  40%  {box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 5px #FF6320;
  background-color: #ff4d00;}
  60%  {box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 7px #FF7A20;
  background-color: #ff6700;}
  80%  {box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 5px #FF6320;
  background-color: #ff4d00;}
  100% {box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 0px #FF9120;
  background-color: #ff8100;}
}

/*@keyframes ray_anim { 
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); transform: rotate(0deg);}    
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg);}
}*/

#stars, #twinkling, #clouds-red, #clouds-red2, #clouds-red3, #clouds-black, .meteor,
#container-sun
{
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
}

/*
** Sun
*/
#container-sun{
  top:-65px;
  left:-75px;
  z-index:2;
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background-color: #ff8100;
  opacity:0.75;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 0px #FF9120; 
  animation: brightness-sun 10s linear infinite;
}

#container-sun > .container-ray {
  position:absolute;
  margin:auto;
  top:0px;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  width:70px;
  animation: ray_anim 120s linear infinite;
}

#container-sun > .container-ray > .ray {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.8) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.8) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); 
    margin-left:10px;
    border-radius:80% 80% 0 0;
    position:absolute;
  
  z-index:2;
    opacity:0.2;
}

.ray-bg{
  height:170px;
  width:20px;
}
@keyframes size-ray-sm{ 
 0%   {height:100px;}
  10%  {height:95px;}
  20%  {height:90px;}
  30%  {height:85px;}
  40%  {height:80px;}
  50%  {height:75px;}
  60%  {height:80px;}
  70%  {height:85px;}
  80%  {height:90px;}
  90%  {height:95px;}
  100% {height:100px;}
}
.ray-sm{
  height: 100px;
  width: 10px;
}

/*Big ray*/
.ray1 {    
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    top:165px;
    left: 15px;
}

.ray-sm.ray2{
  animation: size-ray-sm 3s linear infinite, move-ray2 3s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes move-ray2{
  0% {transform: rotate(-30deg);top: 150px;left: 85px;}
  10% {left:84px;}
  20% {left:83px;}
  30% {left:82px;}
  40% {left:81px;}
  50% {transform: rotate(-31deg);left:80px;}
  60% {left:81px;}
  70% {left:82px;}
  80% {left:83px;}
  90% {left:84px;}
  100% {transform: rotate(-30deg);top: 150px;left: 85px;}
}

.ray-sm.ray4{
  animation: size-ray-sm 3s linear infinite, move-ray4 3s linear infinite;
} 
@keyframes move-ray4{
  0% {transform: rotate(-78deg);top: 45px;left: 150px;}
  10% {left:149px;}
  20% {top:46px;left:148px;}
  30% {left:147px;}
  40% {left:146px;}
  50% { transform: rotate(-79deg);left:145px;}
  60% {left:146px;}
  70% {left:147px;}
  80% {top:46px;left:148px;}
  90% {left:149px;}
  100% {transform: rotate(-78deg);top: 45px;left: 150px;}
}
/*Small ray*/
.ray2 {    
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
    top: 150px;
    left: 85px;
}

/*Big ray*/
.ray3 {
  transform: rotate(-50deg);
  top: 95px;
  left: 150px; 
}

/*Small ray*/
.ray4 {
  transform: rotate(-78deg);
  top: 45px;
  left: 150px;   
}

.meteor{
  /*background: transparent url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/139/139699.svg') no-repeat top center;*/
  /*background: transparent url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/180/180707.svg') no-repeat top center;*/
  /*background: transparent url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/728/728096.svg') no-repeat top center;*/
  background: transparent url('http://i.imgur.com/KgvLW3q.png') no-repeat top center;
  /*background: transparent url('https://i.imgur.com/hwRmI29.png') no-repeat top center;*/
  
  background-size:25px;
}

/*
** Small meteors
*/

.meteor1-sm, .meteor2-sm, .meteor3-sm, .meteor4-sm, .meteor5-sm{
  z-index:2;
}

.meteor1-sm{
  animation:small-meteor 16s linear infinite, move-meteor1-sm 16s linear infinite;
}

.meteor2-sm{
  animation:small-meteor 16s linear infinite, move-meteor2-sm 16s linear infinite;
}

.meteor3-sm{
  animation:small-meteor 16s linear infinite, move-meteor3-sm 16s linear infinite;
}

.meteor4-sm{
  animation:small-meteor 16s linear infinite, move-meteor4-sm 16s linear infinite;
}

.meteor5-sm{
  animation:small-meteor 16s linear infinite, move-meteor5-sm 16s linear infinite;
}

/*
** Big meteors
*/

.meteor1-bg, .meteor2-bg, .meteor3-bg, .meteor4-bg{
  z-index:6;
}
.meteor1-bg{
  animation:big-meteor 8s linear infinite, move-meteor1-bg 8s linear infinite;
}

.meteor2-bg{
  animation:big-meteor 8s linear infinite, move-meteor2-bg 8s linear infinite;
}

.meteor3-bg{
  animation:big-meteor 8s linear infinite, move-meteor3-bg 8s linear infinite;
}

.meteor4-bg{
  animation:big-meteor 8s linear infinite, move-meteor4-bg 8s linear infinite; 
}

/*
** Medium meteors
*/
.meteor1-md, .meteor2-md{
  z-index:4;
}

.meteor1-md{
  animation:medium-meteor 12s linear infinite, move-meteor1-md 12s linear infinite; 
}

.meteor2-md{
  animation:medium-meteor 12s linear infinite, move-meteor2-md 12s linear infinite; 
}

/*
** Stars
*/

#stars {
  background:#000 url('http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/360/images/stars.png') repeat top center;
  z-index:0;
}


/*
** Twinkling stars
*/
#twinkling{
  background:transparent url('http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/360/images/twinkling.png') repeat top center;
  z-index:1;
  
  -moz-animation:move-twink-back 100s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation:move-twink-back 100s linear infinite;
  -o-animation:move-twink-back 100s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation:move-twink-back 150s linear infinite;
  animation:move-twink-back 150s linear infinite;
}

/*
** Black clouds
*/
#clouds-black{
    background:transparent url('http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/360/images/clouds2.png') repeat-x left top;
  z-index:2;
   opacity:0.7;
  -moz-animation:move-clouds-back 200s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation:move-clouds-back 200s linear infinite;
  -o-animation:move-clouds-back 200s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation:move-clouds-back 200s linear infinite;
  animation:move-clouds-back 280s linear infinite;
}

/*
** Red clouds
*/

#clouds-red {
  z-index:3;
}

/*
** Movement of red clouds
*/
#clouds-red, #clouds-red2, #clouds-red3 {
  background: transparent url('http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/360/images/clouds3.png') repeat-x left center;
  
  -moz-animation:move-clouds-back-red 200s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation:move-clouds-back-red 200s linear infinite;
  -o-animation:move-clouds-back-red 200s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation:move-clouds-back-red 200s linear infinite;
  animation:move-clouds-back-red 200s linear infinite;
}
#clouds-red2{
  z-index:4;
}
#clouds-red3{
  z-index:5;
}

body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

#word{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

 
#word > div{
  max-width:100%;
  font-size:50px;
  z-index:10;
  background: orange;
  color: #FFDD1B;
  font-family: Pacifico;
}

#word > div:hover{
  color:#FFF;
  animation: neon 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes neon {
  from {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #FFDD1B, 0 0 70px #FFDD1B, 0 0 80px #FFDD1B, 0 0 100px #FFDD1B, 0 0 150px #FFDD1B;
  }
  to {
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 15px #fff, 0 0 20px #FFDD1B, 0 0 35px #FFDD1B, 0 0 40px #FFDD1B, 0 0 50px #FFDD1B, 0 0 75px #FFDD1B;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="word">
  <div>Galaxy</div>
</div>
<div id="container-sun">
  <div class="container-ray">
    <div class="ray ray-bg ray1"></div>
    <div class="ray ray-sm ray2"></div>
    <div class="ray ray-bg ray3"></div>
    <div class="ray ray-sm ray4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="stars"></div>
<div id="twinkling"></div>
<div id="clouds-red"></div>
<div id="clouds-red2"></div>
<div class="meteor meteor1-sm"></div>
<div class="meteor meteor2-sm"></div>
<div class="meteor meteor3-sm"></div>
<div class="meteor meteor4-sm"></div>
<div class="meteor meteor1-md"></div>
<div class="meteor meteor2-md"></div>
<div class="meteor meteor1-bg"></div>
<div class="meteor meteor2-bg"></div>
<div class="meteor meteor3-bg"></div>
<div class="meteor meteor4-bg"></div>
<div id="clouds-red3"></div>
<div id="clouds-black"></div>
```

Comment: ¿Siempre con flexbox hay que agregar un height de 100% en las etiquetas body y html?

Comment: Teniendo en cuenta que se necesita una referencia o contenedor para la posición, me temo que en este contexto específico, sí.

Answer (score 2):

Hay varias formas de centrar un **div** una de ellas es poniendo el siguiente estilo. Lo que hace el estilo es calcular la distancia  que debe estar desde el top y left con tu div (en este caso el 50% del div conetenedor) y solo son aplicables cuando se tiene el atributo **position** en el valor **absolute** o **fixed** hasta ese punto la esquina superior izquierda de tu **div** seria el centro del div contenedor. Para centrar el div interno se usa después el **transform** mas el **translate** que lo centra a ese punto exacto del centro tanto vertical y horizontal.

```
.div-center {
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

}

Ejemplo Modificado

```css
* {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
@keyframes move-twink-back {
    from {background-position:0 0;}
    to {background-position:-5000px 5000px;}
}
@keyframes move-clouds-back {
    from {background-position: 0;}
    to {background-position:10000px 0;}
}

@keyframes move-clouds-back-red {
    from {background-position: 0;}
    to {background-position:10000px 0;}
}

@keyframes small-meteor {
  0%   {background-size:15px;}
  25%  {background-size:20px;}
  50%  {background-size:25px;}
  75%  {background-size:20px;}
  100% {background-size:15px;}
}

@keyframes move-meteor1-sm {
  from {background-position:500px -500px;}
  to   {background-position:80px 900px;}
}
@keyframes move-meteor2-sm{
  from {background-position:800px -80px;}
  to   {background-position:380px 900px;}
}
@keyframes move-meteor3-sm{
  from {background-position:100px -300px;}
  to   {background-position:-180px 900px;}
}
@keyframes move-meteor4-sm{
  from {background-position:2500px 100px;}
  to   {background-position:1200px 900px;}
}
@keyframes move-meteor5-sm{
  from {background-position:1200px 100px;}
  to   {background-position:800px 900px;}
}

@keyframes big-meteor {
  0%   {background-size:35px;}
  25%  {background-size:45px;}
  50%  {background-size:55px;}
  75%  {background-size:45px;}
  100% {background-size:35px;}
}
@keyframes move-meteor1-bg{
  from {background-position:680px -150px;}
  to   {background-position:100px 900px;}
}
@keyframes move-meteor2-bg{
  from {background-position:1500px -10px;}
  to   {background-position:850px 900px;}
}
@keyframes move-meteor3-bg{
  from {background-position:1000px -500px;}
  to   {background-position:450px 900px;}
}
@keyframes move-meteor4-bg{
  from {background-position:250px -850px;}
  to   {background-position:-550px 900px;}
}

@keyframes medium-meteor{
  0%   {background-size:25px;}
  25%  {background-size:30px;}
  50%  {background-size:35px;}
  75%  {background-size:30px;}
  100% {background-size:25px;}
}

@keyframes move-meteor1-md{
  from {background-position:380px -10px;}
  to   {background-position:-450px 1900px;}
}
@keyframes move-meteor2-md{
  from {background-position:950px -10px;}
  to   {background-position:450px 1900px;}
}
 
@keyframes brightness-sun{
  20%  {box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 3px #FF7A20;
  background-color: #ff6700;}
  40%  {box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 5px #FF6320;
  background-color: #ff4d00;}
  60%  {box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 7px #FF7A20;
  background-color: #ff6700;}
  80%  {box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 5px #FF6320;
  background-color: #ff4d00;}
  100% {box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 0px #FF9120;
  background-color: #ff8100;}
}

/*@keyframes ray_anim { 
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); transform: rotate(0deg);}    
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg);}
}*/

#stars, #twinkling, #clouds-red, #clouds-red2, #clouds-red3, #clouds-black, .meteor,
#container-sun
{
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
}

/*
** Sun
*/
#container-sun{
  top:-65px;
  left:-75px;
  z-index:2;
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background-color: #ff8100;
  opacity:0.75;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 0px #FF9120; 
  animation: brightness-sun 10s linear infinite;
}

#container-sun > .container-ray {
  position:absolute;
  margin:auto;
  top:0px;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  width:70px;
  animation: ray_anim 120s linear infinite;
}

#container-sun > .container-ray > .ray {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.8) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.8) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); 
    margin-left:10px;
    border-radius:80% 80% 0 0;
    position:absolute;
  
  z-index:2;
    opacity:0.2;
}

.ray-bg{
  height:170px;
  width:20px;
}
@keyframes size-ray-sm{ 
 0%   {height:100px;}
  10%  {height:95px;}
  20%  {height:90px;}
  30%  {height:85px;}
  40%  {height:80px;}
  50%  {height:75px;}
  60%  {height:80px;}
  70%  {height:85px;}
  80%  {height:90px;}
  90%  {height:95px;}
  100% {height:100px;}
}
.ray-sm{
  height: 100px;
  width: 10px;
}

/*Big ray*/
.ray1 {    
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    top:165px;
    left: 15px;
}

.ray-sm.ray2{
  animation: size-ray-sm 3s linear infinite, move-ray2 3s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes move-ray2{
  0% {transform: rotate(-30deg);top: 150px;left: 85px;}
  10% {left:84px;}
  20% {left:83px;}
  30% {left:82px;}
  40% {left:81px;}
  50% {transform: rotate(-31deg);left:80px;}
  60% {left:81px;}
  70% {left:82px;}
  80% {left:83px;}
  90% {left:84px;}
  100% {transform: rotate(-30deg);top: 150px;left: 85px;}
}

.ray-sm.ray4{
  animation: size-ray-sm 3s linear infinite, move-ray4 3s linear infinite;
} 
@keyframes move-ray4{
  0% {transform: rotate(-78deg);top: 45px;left: 150px;}
  10% {left:149px;}
  20% {top:46px;left:148px;}
  30% {left:147px;}
  40% {left:146px;}
  50% { transform: rotate(-79deg);left:145px;}
  60% {left:146px;}
  70% {left:147px;}
  80% {top:46px;left:148px;}
  90% {left:149px;}
  100% {transform: rotate(-78deg);top: 45px;left: 150px;}
}
/*Small ray*/
.ray2 {    
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
    top: 150px;
    left: 85px;
}

/*Big ray*/
.ray3 {
  transform: rotate(-50deg);
  top: 95px;
  left: 150px; 
}

/*Small ray*/
.ray4 {
  transform: rotate(-78deg);
  top: 45px;
  left: 150px;   
}

.meteor{
  /*background: transparent url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/139/139699.svg') no-repeat top center;*/
  /*background: transparent url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/180/180707.svg') no-repeat top center;*/
  /*background: transparent url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/728/728096.svg') no-repeat top center;*/
  background: transparent url('http://i.imgur.com/KgvLW3q.png') no-repeat top center;
  /*background: transparent url('https://i.imgur.com/hwRmI29.png') no-repeat top center;*/
  
  background-size:25px;
}

/*
** Small meteors
*/

.meteor1-sm, .meteor2-sm, .meteor3-sm, .meteor4-sm, .meteor5-sm{
  z-index:2;
}

.meteor1-sm{
  animation:small-meteor 16s linear infinite, move-meteor1-sm 16s linear infinite;
}

.meteor2-sm{
  animation:small-meteor 16s linear infinite, move-meteor2-sm 16s linear infinite;
}

.meteor3-sm{
  animation:small-meteor 16s linear infinite, move-meteor3-sm 16s linear infinite;
}

.meteor4-sm{
  animation:small-meteor 16s linear infinite, move-meteor4-sm 16s linear infinite;
}

.meteor5-sm{
  animation:small-meteor 16s linear infinite, move-meteor5-sm 16s linear infinite;
}

/*
** Big meteors
*/

.meteor1-bg, .meteor2-bg, .meteor3-bg, .meteor4-bg{
  z-index:6;
}
.meteor1-bg{
  animation:big-meteor 8s linear infinite, move-meteor1-bg 8s linear infinite;
}

.meteor2-bg{
  animation:big-meteor 8s linear infinite, move-meteor2-bg 8s linear infinite;
}

.meteor3-bg{
  animation:big-meteor 8s linear infinite, move-meteor3-bg 8s linear infinite;
}

.meteor4-bg{
  animation:big-meteor 8s linear infinite, move-meteor4-bg 8s linear infinite; 
}

/*
** Medium meteors
*/
.meteor1-md, .meteor2-md{
  z-index:4;
}

.meteor1-md{
  animation:medium-meteor 12s linear infinite, move-meteor1-md 12s linear infinite; 
}

.meteor2-md{
  animation:medium-meteor 12s linear infinite, move-meteor2-md 12s linear infinite; 
}

/*
** Stars
*/

#stars {
  background:#000 url('http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/360/images/stars.png') repeat top center;
  z-index:0;
}


/*
** Twinkling stars
*/
#twinkling{
  background:transparent url('http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/360/images/twinkling.png') repeat top center;
  z-index:1;
  
  -moz-animation:move-twink-back 100s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation:move-twink-back 100s linear infinite;
  -o-animation:move-twink-back 100s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation:move-twink-back 150s linear infinite;
  animation:move-twink-back 150s linear infinite;
}

/*
** Black clouds
*/
#clouds-black{
    background:transparent url('http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/360/images/clouds2.png') repeat-x left top;
  z-index:2;
   opacity:0.7;
  -moz-animation:move-clouds-back 200s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation:move-clouds-back 200s linear infinite;
  -o-animation:move-clouds-back 200s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation:move-clouds-back 200s linear infinite;
  animation:move-clouds-back 280s linear infinite;
}

/*
** Red clouds
*/

#clouds-red {
  z-index:3;
}

/*
** Movement of red clouds
*/
#clouds-red, #clouds-red2, #clouds-red3 {
  background: transparent url('http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/360/images/clouds3.png') repeat-x left center;
  
  -moz-animation:move-clouds-back-red 200s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation:move-clouds-back-red 200s linear infinite;
  -o-animation:move-clouds-back-red 200s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation:move-clouds-back-red 200s linear infinite;
  animation:move-clouds-back-red 200s linear infinite;
}
#clouds-red2{
  z-index:4;
}
#clouds-red3{
  z-index:5;
}

#word{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  text-align:center;
}

#word:before{
  content: "";
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  height:100%;
}
 
#word > div{
  max-width:100%;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  font-size:50px;
  z-index:10;
  background: orange;
  position:absolute;
  color: #FFDD1B;
  font-family: Pacifico;
}

#word > div:hover{
  color:#FFF;
  animation: neon 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes neon {
  from {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #FFDD1B, 0 0 70px #FFDD1B, 0 0 80px #FFDD1B, 0 0 100px #FFDD1B, 0 0 150px #FFDD1B;
  }
  to {
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 15px #fff, 0 0 20px #FFDD1B, 0 0 35px #FFDD1B, 0 0 40px #FFDD1B, 0 0 50px #FFDD1B, 0 0 75px #FFDD1B;
  }
}

.div-center {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="word"  >
  <div class="div-center">Galaxy</div>
</div>
<div id="container-sun">
  <div class="container-ray">
    <div class="ray ray-bg ray1"></div>
    <div class="ray ray-sm ray2"></div>
    <div class="ray ray-bg ray3"></div>
    <div class="ray ray-sm ray4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="stars"></div>
<div id="twinkling"></div>
<div id="clouds-red"></div>
<div id="clouds-red2"></div>
<div class="meteor meteor1-sm"></div>
<div class="meteor meteor2-sm"></div>
<div class="meteor meteor3-sm"></div>
<div class="meteor meteor4-sm"></div>
<div class="meteor meteor1-md"></div>
<div class="meteor meteor2-md"></div>
<div class="meteor meteor1-bg"></div>
<div class="meteor meteor2-bg"></div>
<div class="meteor meteor3-bg"></div>
<div class="meteor meteor4-bg"></div>
<div id="clouds-red3"></div>
<div id="clouds-black"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

La forma màs sencilla y nativa es usar `display table` al 100% con `display table cell` y al cell agregar `vertical align middle` con `text align center`.

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes hacer utilizando las propiedades `top`, `bottom`, `left` y `right` y dejándolas en 0, que, combinado con la propiedad `margin: auto` te centrará el div en el centro de la pantalla.

Ten en cuenta que le tendrás que poner una anchura y una altura fijas ya que si no el div se te expandirá tanto como pueda, es decir, te ocupará toda la pantalla.

```
#word > div{
  max-height: 60px; /* NUEVO */
  max-width: 180px; /* NUEVO */
  display: inline-block;
  font-size:50px;
  z-index:10;
  background: orange;
  position:absolute;
  color: #FFDD1B;
  font-family: Pacifico;
  top: 0; /* NUEVO */
  left: 0; /* NUEVO */
  right: 0; /* NUEVO */
  bottom: 0; /* NUEVO */
  margin: auto; /* NUEVO */
}
```

Tu ejemplo modificado:

```css
* {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
@keyframes move-twink-back {
    from {background-position:0 0;}
    to {background-position:-5000px 5000px;}
}
@keyframes move-clouds-back {
    from {background-position: 0;}
    to {background-position:10000px 0;}
}

@keyframes move-clouds-back-red {
    from {background-position: 0;}
    to {background-position:10000px 0;}
}

@keyframes small-meteor {
  0%   {background-size:15px;}
  25%  {background-size:20px;}
  50%  {background-size:25px;}
  75%  {background-size:20px;}
  100% {background-size:15px;}
}

@keyframes move-meteor1-sm {
  from {background-position:500px -500px;}
  to   {background-position:80px 900px;}
}
@keyframes move-meteor2-sm{
  from {background-position:800px -80px;}
  to   {background-position:380px 900px;}
}
@keyframes move-meteor3-sm{
  from {background-position:100px -300px;}
  to   {background-position:-180px 900px;}
}
@keyframes move-meteor4-sm{
  from {background-position:2500px 100px;}
  to   {background-position:1200px 900px;}
}
@keyframes move-meteor5-sm{
  from {background-position:1200px 100px;}
  to   {background-position:800px 900px;}
}

@keyframes big-meteor {
  0%   {background-size:35px;}
  25%  {background-size:45px;}
  50%  {background-size:55px;}
  75%  {background-size:45px;}
  100% {background-size:35px;}
}
@keyframes move-meteor1-bg{
  from {background-position:680px -150px;}
  to   {background-position:100px 900px;}
}
@keyframes move-meteor2-bg{
  from {background-position:1500px -10px;}
  to   {background-position:850px 900px;}
}
@keyframes move-meteor3-bg{
  from {background-position:1000px -500px;}
  to   {background-position:450px 900px;}
}
@keyframes move-meteor4-bg{
  from {background-position:250px -850px;}
  to   {background-position:-550px 900px;}
}

@keyframes medium-meteor{
  0%   {background-size:25px;}
  25%  {background-size:30px;}
  50%  {background-size:35px;}
  75%  {background-size:30px;}
  100% {background-size:25px;}
}

@keyframes move-meteor1-md{
  from {background-position:380px -10px;}
  to   {background-position:-450px 1900px;}
}
@keyframes move-meteor2-md{
  from {background-position:950px -10px;}
  to   {background-position:450px 1900px;}
}
 
@keyframes brightness-sun{
  20%  {box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 3px #FF7A20;
  background-color: #ff6700;}
  40%  {box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 5px #FF6320;
  background-color: #ff4d00;}
  60%  {box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 7px #FF7A20;
  background-color: #ff6700;}
  80%  {box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 5px #FF6320;
  background-color: #ff4d00;}
  100% {box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 0px #FF9120;
  background-color: #ff8100;}
}

/*@keyframes ray_anim { 
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); transform: rotate(0deg);}    
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg);}
}*/

#stars, #twinkling, #clouds-red, #clouds-red2, #clouds-red3, #clouds-black, .meteor,
#container-sun
{
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
}

/*
** Sun
*/
#container-sun{
  top:-65px;
  left:-75px;
  z-index:2;
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background-color: #ff8100;
  opacity:0.75;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 0px #FF9120; 
  animation: brightness-sun 10s linear infinite;
}

#container-sun > .container-ray {
  position:absolute;
  margin:auto;
  top:0px;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  width:70px;
  animation: ray_anim 120s linear infinite;
}

#container-sun > .container-ray > .ray {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.8) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.8) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); 
    margin-left:10px;
    border-radius:80% 80% 0 0;
    position:absolute;
  
  z-index:2;
    opacity:0.2;
}

.ray-bg{
  height:170px;
  width:20px;
}
@keyframes size-ray-sm{ 
 0%   {height:100px;}
  10%  {height:95px;}
  20%  {height:90px;}
  30%  {height:85px;}
  40%  {height:80px;}
  50%  {height:75px;}
  60%  {height:80px;}
  70%  {height:85px;}
  80%  {height:90px;}
  90%  {height:95px;}
  100% {height:100px;}
}
.ray-sm{
  height: 100px;
  width: 10px;
}

/*Big ray*/
.ray1 {    
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    top:165px;
    left: 15px;
}

.ray-sm.ray2{
  animation: size-ray-sm 3s linear infinite, move-ray2 3s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes move-ray2{
  0% {transform: rotate(-30deg);top: 150px;left: 85px;}
  10% {left:84px;}
  20% {left:83px;}
  30% {left:82px;}
  40% {left:81px;}
  50% {transform: rotate(-31deg);left:80px;}
  60% {left:81px;}
  70% {left:82px;}
  80% {left:83px;}
  90% {left:84px;}
  100% {transform: rotate(-30deg);top: 150px;left: 85px;}
}

.ray-sm.ray4{
  animation: size-ray-sm 3s linear infinite, move-ray4 3s linear infinite;
} 
@keyframes move-ray4{
  0% {transform: rotate(-78deg);top: 45px;left: 150px;}
  10% {left:149px;}
  20% {top:46px;left:148px;}
  30% {left:147px;}
  40% {left:146px;}
  50% { transform: rotate(-79deg);left:145px;}
  60% {left:146px;}
  70% {left:147px;}
  80% {top:46px;left:148px;}
  90% {left:149px;}
  100% {transform: rotate(-78deg);top: 45px;left: 150px;}
}
/*Small ray*/
.ray2 {    
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
    top: 150px;
    left: 85px;
}

/*Big ray*/
.ray3 {
  transform: rotate(-50deg);
  top: 95px;
  left: 150px; 
}

/*Small ray*/
.ray4 {
  transform: rotate(-78deg);
  top: 45px;
  left: 150px;   
}

.meteor{
  /*background: transparent url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/139/139699.svg') no-repeat top center;*/
  /*background: transparent url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/180/180707.svg') no-repeat top center;*/
  /*background: transparent url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/728/728096.svg') no-repeat top center;*/
  background: transparent url('http://i.imgur.com/KgvLW3q.png') no-repeat top center;
  /*background: transparent url('https://i.imgur.com/hwRmI29.png') no-repeat top center;*/
  
  background-size:25px;
}

/*
** Small meteors
*/

.meteor1-sm, .meteor2-sm, .meteor3-sm, .meteor4-sm, .meteor5-sm{
  z-index:2;
}

.meteor1-sm{
  animation:small-meteor 16s linear infinite, move-meteor1-sm 16s linear infinite;
}

.meteor2-sm{
  animation:small-meteor 16s linear infinite, move-meteor2-sm 16s linear infinite;
}

.meteor3-sm{
  animation:small-meteor 16s linear infinite, move-meteor3-sm 16s linear infinite;
}

.meteor4-sm{
  animation:small-meteor 16s linear infinite, move-meteor4-sm 16s linear infinite;
}

.meteor5-sm{
  animation:small-meteor 16s linear infinite, move-meteor5-sm 16s linear infinite;
}

/*
** Big meteors
*/

.meteor1-bg, .meteor2-bg, .meteor3-bg, .meteor4-bg{
  z-index:6;
}
.meteor1-bg{
  animation:big-meteor 8s linear infinite, move-meteor1-bg 8s linear infinite;
}

.meteor2-bg{
  animation:big-meteor 8s linear infinite, move-meteor2-bg 8s linear infinite;
}

.meteor3-bg{
  animation:big-meteor 8s linear infinite, move-meteor3-bg 8s linear infinite;
}

.meteor4-bg{
  animation:big-meteor 8s linear infinite, move-meteor4-bg 8s linear infinite; 
}

/*
** Medium meteors
*/
.meteor1-md, .meteor2-md{
  z-index:4;
}

.meteor1-md{
  animation:medium-meteor 12s linear infinite, move-meteor1-md 12s linear infinite; 
}

.meteor2-md{
  animation:medium-meteor 12s linear infinite, move-meteor2-md 12s linear infinite; 
}

/*
** Stars
*/

#stars {
  background:#000 url('http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/360/images/stars.png') repeat top center;
  z-index:0;
}


/*
** Twinkling stars
*/
#twinkling{
  background:transparent url('http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/360/images/twinkling.png') repeat top center;
  z-index:1;
  
  -moz-animation:move-twink-back 100s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation:move-twink-back 100s linear infinite;
  -o-animation:move-twink-back 100s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation:move-twink-back 150s linear infinite;
  animation:move-twink-back 150s linear infinite;
}

/*
** Black clouds
*/
#clouds-black{
    background:transparent url('http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/360/images/clouds2.png') repeat-x left top;
  z-index:2;
   opacity:0.7;
  -moz-animation:move-clouds-back 200s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation:move-clouds-back 200s linear infinite;
  -o-animation:move-clouds-back 200s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation:move-clouds-back 200s linear infinite;
  animation:move-clouds-back 280s linear infinite;
}

/*
** Red clouds
*/

#clouds-red {
  z-index:3;
}

/*
** Movement of red clouds
*/
#clouds-red, #clouds-red2, #clouds-red3 {
  background: transparent url('http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/360/images/clouds3.png') repeat-x left center;
  
  -moz-animation:move-clouds-back-red 200s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation:move-clouds-back-red 200s linear infinite;
  -o-animation:move-clouds-back-red 200s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation:move-clouds-back-red 200s linear infinite;
  animation:move-clouds-back-red 200s linear infinite;
}
#clouds-red2{
  z-index:4;
}
#clouds-red3{
  z-index:5;
}

#word{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  text-align:center;
}

#word:before{
  content: "";
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  height:100%;
}
 
#word > div{
  max-height: 60px;
  max-width: 180px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size:50px;
  z-index:10;
  background: orange;
  position:absolute;
  color: #FFDD1B;
  font-family: Pacifico;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

#word > div:hover{
  color:#FFF;
  animation: neon 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes neon {
  from {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #FFDD1B, 0 0 70px #FFDD1B, 0 0 80px #FFDD1B, 0 0 100px #FFDD1B, 0 0 150px #FFDD1B;
  }
  to {
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 15px #fff, 0 0 20px #FFDD1B, 0 0 35px #FFDD1B, 0 0 40px #FFDD1B, 0 0 50px #FFDD1B, 0 0 75px #FFDD1B;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="word">
  <div>Galaxy</div>
</div>
<div id="container-sun">
  <div class="container-ray">
    <div class="ray ray-bg ray1"></div>
    <div class="ray ray-sm ray2"></div>
    <div class="ray ray-bg ray3"></div>
    <div class="ray ray-sm ray4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="stars"></div>
<div id="twinkling"></div>
<div id="clouds-red"></div>
<div id="clouds-red2"></div>
<div class="meteor meteor1-sm"></div>
<div class="meteor meteor2-sm"></div>
<div class="meteor meteor3-sm"></div>
<div class="meteor meteor4-sm"></div>
<div class="meteor meteor1-md"></div>
<div class="meteor meteor2-md"></div>
<div class="meteor meteor1-bg"></div>
<div class="meteor meteor2-bg"></div>
<div class="meteor meteor3-bg"></div>
<div class="meteor meteor4-bg"></div>
<div id="clouds-red3"></div>
<div id="clouds-black"></div>
```